# Unordered list checkboxlist control

Tags: c#, visual-web-developer

I want to use a CheckBoxList control which prints out HTML using

```
<UL>
    <LI><INPUT CHECKBOX></LI>
    <LI>etc</LI>
</UL>
```

For the markup.

However if I try the following:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="lstShipsInScope" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="ShipsInScope" DataTextField="Ship_Name" DataValueField="Ship_Id"
     ondatabound="lstShipsInScope_DataBound" AutoPostBack="True"
     RepeatLayout="unorderedlist" RepeatDirection="horizontal">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I get:

```
Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeatLayout' from its string representation 'unorderedlist' for the 'RepeatLayout' property.
```

Which seems silly given that unorderedlist is offered as a value for the RepeatLayout attribute. Flow works, which puts them all in a span and so does table, but I want to use an unorderedlist and do the styling myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/596468/vs2010-intellisense-%20uses-incorrect-version-of-net-framework) be the problem?

"In Visual Studio 2010, when you create a project based on the .NET 3.5 framework, the Intellisense and Designer both still function as if the project is .NET 4.0 framework."

Thus intellisense provides options that aren't actually available, in this case "UnorderedList" which is new to .NET 4.0.  To resolve the problem, either:

1. Upgrade the project to .NET 4.0.
2. Don't use the value that is not available (in this case, "RepeatLayout.UnorderedList")

Comment: Probably - how do I convert my project to .NET 4 then, if that's not too crazy an idea?

Comment: Just right-click the project, select Target Framework ".NET Framework 4".

Comment: Awesome. Edit your answer so as to not rely on that link and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

```
RepeatDirection="vertical"
```

The repeat direction should be vertical.